# How do I get all the text nodes in a HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a way to get all text nodes in a HTML document? I mean something like

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

but for text nodes?

Or, do I have to walk the DOM to get them?

Comment: Yes, that seems correct, @null. Bad searching on my side. What do I do now?

Comment: @Leo delete this ques or wait for someone to make it as duplicate

Comment: Ok, I see now I can delete it. Thanks @Pilot. I will do that since it is useless. Eh, no too late. Flagging it instead. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2):

`NodeIterator` with `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator

Comment: Thanks, but the question was a duplicate. Sorry.